# Windows 7 USB network dongle: the device cannot start error code 10

Tags: windows-7, usb, dongle

I am experiencing problems with an assex network adapter dongle on Windows 7 Service Pack 1 
with all latest drivers installed.

After every ACPI shutdown or even sometimes on normal shutdowns from the start menu, at the next OS start the network adapter is not usable and device manager shows the error:

```
the device cannot start : error code 10
```

A reboot usually solves the issue, but sometimes  I have to unplug power from the PC and plug it again to get the adapter back to a usable state.

I tried on multiple PCs and with multiple dongles getting the same problems, so I don't think it's related to a single defective hardware piece.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I did a search for `assex network adapter` and the first thing that came up was this question. I really don't want to talk about the results I got for `assex`, but suffice it to say I think you'll need to provide more information on the dongle in question to get any useful answers here.